# pip setuptools missing in ubuntu 17.04

Tags: ubuntu, pip, setuptools

i have a very strange issue with the new ubuntu 17.04 when i try to install something from pip i am unable to do it ... this is the error :

```
sudo pip install psutil

The directory '/home/metu/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/metu/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting psutil
Downloading psutil-5.2.2.tar.gz (348kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 358kB 1.3MB/s 
Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source 
distribution.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 387, in setup_py
 import setuptools  # noqa
 File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-32.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/setuptools/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
 File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-32.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/setuptools/extern/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: No module named extern
```

this will happen with any of the tools i want to install es. beautifulsoap , flask ecc ...

Python is the version :

```
Python 2.7.13
```

Pip is the latest version :

```
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

setuptools is installed :

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
python-setuptools is already the newest version (33.1.1-1).
```

using pycharm the packages are installed correctly but i have many library to include and i can't install one by one and some are missing like flask-login library ...

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

extern is needed and isn't installed so download extern :

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/extern
```

and install it with the command :

```
python setup.py install
```

and if the problem is not solved uninstall setuptools from pip

```
pip uninstall setuptools
```